# BadRequestError in python when iterating AppEngine NDB

Tags: python, google-app-engine, iterator, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

This is a simplified snippet of code:

```
ndb_query_iter = ndbObject.query().iter(keys_only=True)
has_next = ndb_query_iter.has_next()
if has_next:
  while has_next:
    deferred.defer(doStuff, ndb_query_iter.next())
    has_next = ndb_query_iter.has_next()
```

I get the following error-message:

```
BadRequestError: invalid handle: <various ndb-id>
```

The issue is with the last line of code:

```
has_next = ndb_query_iter.has_next()
```

Comment: Why mess with `has_next` at all?  Why not just `for key in ndb_query_iter: deferred.defer(doStuff, key)`?

Comment: `if has_next: while has_next: has_next = ndb_query_iter.has_next()` that is a strange construction, you might as well do `while ndb_query_iter.has_next():`

Comment: Issue persist when structured as a for-loop. I figured I'd expand it to make the  problem more apparent.

Comment: I dont find any problem with your snippet. Can you post the error stack trace?